# Computer shutsdowns when trying to boot

Tags: boot, overheating

I have an IBM ThinkCentre, and I was talking to someone on Skype when it suddenly just shutoff. When I rebooted it asked me to start windows normally or in safe mode, but as soon I choose an option (Any of them) it shuts back down. So I thought it was a problem with windows and tired booting from a Hirens disk, but same thing. I've been using this computer without problems for over a year know. Any idea's for me to try? Unfortunatly I don't have any powersupplies or extra RAM to switch out to try anything like that.

**EDIT**
I left it off for a while and it's booting to windows now. I would still like to know what might have been causing it to do that if you have any ideas.

Comment: I would guess that something's busted.  You need someone to look at it who has hardware debugging skills/tools.

Comment: desktop? aio? probably overheating is what I am guessing.... check all fans: cpu, case, gfx cards

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Logman, sounds like a temperature issue and the system is shutting itself down as a safeguard to avoid permanent damage.

There is a small program call open hardware monitor that you can DL to watch the CPU temp, fan speed and so on [open hardware monitor.](http://openhardwaremonitor.org/) It may be a good first place to start your trouble shooting and then fix/replace the offending hardware.

Answer (score 0):

there are varoius thermostats on the mother board also. Usully a 6 pin small pitch IC that regulate fan speed and various other control aspects assocated with heat regulation. If you have no luck with you solution so far check the pins on those devices.

A multimeter and check vcc and ground will give you some indication if the device is functioning properly.